# Facebook Like plugin gives 'could not be reached' due to redirect headers?

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-like

I am trying on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

A. In URL to Like, I provide this tinyurl - `http://tinyurl.com/7qxuvr5`. This tinyurl redirects to something like `http://rsp3.rsys2.net/pub/sf/FormLink`. When I Like tinyurl, it works.

B. In URL to Like, I provide this other URL_B - `http://rsp3.rsys2.net/pub/cc?_ri_=X0Gzc2X%3DWQpglLjHJlTQGsyk7oNL0UB7Bt6zdElRzdUocTR3zgnTzd3BMOVXtpKX%3DSUSWY&_ei_=EllxcGK7968SUmYSYUrLBBomgA-Y`. It also redirects to something like `http://rsp3.rsys2.net/pub/sf/FormLink`. When I Like this URL_B, I get Error - The page at `http://rsp3.rsys2.net/pub/sf/FormLink` could not be reached - though it is a valid page I can reach via browser.

`http://rsp3.rsys2.net/pub/sf/FormLink` page served by both [A] and [B] have same layout and structure.

I see that tinyurl redirects using 301 and URL_B redirects using 302.

Could you please guide why this may be issue?
I want user to be able to Like URL_B - but that is not working for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your second link is missing part of the redirected tiny link.

Truncated tiny redirect:

```
http://rsp3.rsys2.net/pub/sf/FormLink?_ri_=X0Gzc2X%3DWQp
```

Truncated link B:

```
http://rsp3.rsys2.net/pub/cc?ri=X0Gzc2X%3DWQp
```

I'm not sure how these links were derived, but B link has `/pub/cc?ri=` where as A has `/pub/sf/FormLink?_ri_=`

They aren't going to the same page.

Comment: During posting on this forum, `_` got truncated. I have corrected link under B in original post. Now both A and B redirect to something like `http://rsp3.rsys2.net/pub/sf/FormLink?_ri_=....`

Comment: I have corrected with more information. Please see if you can guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, the corrected link if forwarding to the same place as the short link. Try replacing your long link with the redirected end point link, and see if your like works after that.

Comment: Like on direct end point link works. But I want to get Like working on URL_B `http://rsp3.rsys2.net/pub/cc` - which I want to figure out why not working.

Comment: Ok, then lets look at the redirect process for URL_B. How and why is it being redirected? If they are essentially the same content, why the different ways of getting there?

Comment: From the way your like buttons work, the Like button on URL_B takes you to the same page that URL_A starts out on, which is the actual working like button. So B is not really the same page as A. B introduces another step in the like process, by redirecting them to A. I'm not sure I follow the logic of this. If you want them to like A why not skip B, if you want B to be separate from A, why not make a specific like button for it, instead of making it redirect to A?